# How to call curl command from python

Tags: python

I have a command as below

```
Result = os.open(“curl -u username:password https://hostname/stafftools/reports/all_users.csv -k”).read()
```

It’s returning nothing.

can someone help me out?

Comment: `os.system(“curl -u username:password https://hostname/stafftools/reports/all_users.csv -k”)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238180/execute-shell-commands-in-python

Comment: This is working fine....problem with curl not available in pycharm.....installed curl in pycharm....then after all commands.....os.open....os.system....subprocess giving same results. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.call(["curl", "-u", "username:password", "https://hostname/stafftools/reports/all_users.csv", "-k"])
```

Find more information [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators).

Comment: It’s working perfectly...thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. If this helped answer your question feel free to accept this as the answer.